# exec user process caused "exec format error"

Tags: docker-compose

I try to run a docker-compose file which runs on an `amd64` architecture but the same docker-compose file on an `armv7` produces

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

The `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '2'
services:
    gitit:
        image: marcelhuberfoo/docker-gitit:latest
#        container_name: gitit 
        restart: always
        networks:
        - frontproxy_default
        - default
        environment:
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=wiki.gerastree.at
        - GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="xx"
        - GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="xx"
        - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=wiki.xx
        - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=xx
        volumes: 
        - /home/frank/Data/wikiFolder/af:/data 
                # the config file is there 
                # (but my.conf is the one used regularly)
        ports:
        - 5001:5001  
networks:
   frontproxy_default:
        external: true
```

which follows the [instructions](https://sitegeist.de/blog/typo3-blog/docker-compose-setup-mit-nginx-reverse-proxy.html).

What can cause this error, which occurs only on the arm architecture, not on amd? What is the best approach to debug? I am fairly new with docker...

Answer (score 0):

The error was "stupid" - the image mentioned `docker-compose.yml` for the nginx-proxy server was not available for the `armv7` architecture.

I used `buildx` to produce one. It can be used as

```
        image: andrewufrank/radical304:2
```

A more appropriate error messages would have been appreciated!